# Brightway - AssertionError while importing ecoinvent 3.5

Tags: python, brightway

I am currently trying to import the ecoinvent 3.5 database in a new project and always get an AssertionError. I think it might be related to the fact that I have already downloaded the database once and have deleted it in the meantime.

It would be great if you could help me with this. Thank you in advance!

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGg0G.png)

Answer (score 0):

That assertion statement verifies if the folder exists. If you navitage to that address you should see that the folder with the ecospold files is not there.

I would download the files from the ecoinvent website and store it in a known location. Then use the import wizard of the activity-browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying recurring issue caused by an interaction between how the operating system handles temporary directories and python.

The temporary directory where the data is unpacked is sometimes created 'too late', or not at all, which then trips the assertion error.

Given that you've already downloaded the ecoinvent 7z archive, it should be visible and selectable from the 'local 7z-archive with ecospold2 files' option. This may help.

If the issue persists, you can also extract the 'datasets' folder from the 7z archive yourself (it lives in the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\EcoInventDownLoader\EcoInventDownLoader` directory), and then use the 'local directory with ecospold2 files' option to avoid temporary directories entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! For the solution I only had to delete the ecospold in the folder you mentioned and start the download again.